# Error TOO MANY REDIRECTS debbuged

Tags: php, apache

I'm spending a few hours trying to solve this `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` without success.

It happens when I access my website URL without being logged in. So if I do not have a session started I will be redirect to -> mywebsite.com/site/login or just /login

The PHP code that makes that is below:

```
if ( isset($_GET['p2k_url']) && $_GET['p2k_url'] ) {

        if ( strstr($_GET['p2k_url'], '/') ) {

            $url = explode('/', $_GET['p2k_url']);

        } else {
            $url[0] = $_GET['p2k_url'];
        }

        if ( !isset($url[1]) || !$url[1] ) {
            $url[1] = 'index';
        }
    }

    if ( $url[0] != 'login' && !$__usuCod ) {
        header('Location: /site/login.php');
        die();
    }

    if ( file_exists(SITE_DIR.DS.'_'.$url[0].DS.$url[1].'.php') ) {

        include SITE_DIR.DS.'_'.$url[0].DS.$url[1].'.php';

    } else {

        if ( file_exists(SITE_DIR.DS.'_'.$url[0].DS.'no404.php') ) {
            include SITE_DIR.DS.'_'.$url[0].DS.'index.php';
        } else {
            include SITE_DIR.DS.'_404'.DS.'index.php';
        }
    }
```

Right here: `if ( $url[0] != 'login' && !$__usuCod ) {`

My login.php is just a simple html page with form. Nothing there to worry about.

Although my main .htaccess is below and I think it might have something there:

Options -indexes

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p2k_url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

In order to debug and find the error, when I run tail -f access_log I get just simple access requests:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2016:11:16:28 -0200] "GET /site/login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Nothing coming on error_log tough.

Doing reseraches I see that is a very comum problem on WP - which is not the case here. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `if ( isset($_GET['p2k_url']) && isset($_GET['p2k_url']) ) {if ( strstr($_GET['p2k_url'], '/') ) {$url = explode('/', $_GET['p2k_url']);} else {$url[0] = $_GET['p2k_url'];}if ( !isset($url[1])) {$url[1] = 'index';}}
if ( $url[0] !== 'login' && !$__usuCod ) {header('Location: /site/login.php');die();}
if ( file_exists(SITE_DIR.DS.'_'.$url[0].DS.$url[1].'.php') ) {include SITE_DIR.DS.'_'.$url[0].DS.$url[1].'.php';} else {if ( file_exists(SITE_DIR.DS.'_'.$url[0].DS.'no404.php') ) {include SITE_DIR.DS.'_'.$url[0].DS.'index.php';} else {include SITE_DIR.DS.'_404'.DS.'index.php';}}`

Comment: just add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to your htaccess file.

Comment: @Federkun I already did that but nothing has changed...

Comment: I had a similar issue. I'd only made some minor javascript changes. I realised that triggering a login redirect over and over while testing pages triggers Chrome to think there is a redirect issue after a while. When I tested the same code in incognito mode there was no problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you're redirecting to `/site/login.php` which your rewrite changes to `index.php?p2k_url=site/login.php`

`$url` will be an array of `['site', 'login.php']` (i'd `trim($x, '/')` the string before exploding to be sure).

Then you test if `$url[0] != 'login'` which will always be true as `[0]` is `site`. You need to test if `$url[1] != 'login.php'` or trim the file extension from the string first.

if you want to allow `/site/login` and `/login` then you just need to work out a rule for that. If `/site/xxx` is always equal to `/xxx` then just remove the first array index from $url if `$url[0] == 'site'` (or normalise your url's properly)

A really useful debugging technique i used in my early days was `var_dump` or `print_r` along with `die()` or `exit`. Use something like `die('xxx')` and move it up and down your script to identify where the redirect is occuring, then print out the variables to see what they contain and check your comparing them correctly. It's a crude method, but it works

Comment: Yes I usually debug with dump or print_r too but in this case it's not bringing what I need. btw the print_r($url) is Array ( [0] => login.php [1] => index )

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['p2k_url']` before you explode it, as i can't see how `index` can be after `login` if the URL's are as stated in your question